# Liferay: Suspend/Disable Guest user

Tags: liferay

How to suspend/disable a guest user in liferay?

Regards
Vishal G

Answer (score 4):

To clarify, Guest is not a specific User, but rather a Role assigned to visitors who have not logged in yet.  Those users with the Guest role are able to view pages in the Guest community.  As far as I know, there is not a way to disable the Guest role -- and if you somehow were able to accomplish this, no one would be able to visit your home/login page to authenticate themselves.  That would render your site basically useless to all users.

If you want to restrict your pages to not be visible to casual browsers (not logged in), you can create those pages into the private section of another community or organization.